# Fragment's onDestroyView called but view is not being destroyed

Tags: android, android-fragments

The Android fragment lifecycle shows that when a fragment is added to the backstack and then removed/replaced, `onDestroyView()` is called, and later on, when the fragment returns to the layout from the backstack, `onCreateView()` is called.

From my understanding it means that the fragment's view is being destroyed and recreated. If the user has input text in an `EditText` in fragment A and goes to fragment B and then back to A, when the fragment comes back the `EditText`'s contents will have been erased.

However, this is not happening in the following code; can anybody explain why? I have already verified that `FragmentA`'s `onDestroyView()` is being called.

[image]

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private Fragment currentFragment = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            addFragment(new FragmentA());
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        this.currentFragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (currentFragment instanceof FragmentB) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        setCurrentFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

### FragmentA.java

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

        final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);

        Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putString("text", editText.getText().toString());
                fragmentB.setArguments(arguments);
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).addFragment(fragmentB);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        Log.d("Tag", "FragmentA.onDestroyView() has been called.");
    }
}
```

### FragmentB.java

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(getArguments().getString("text"));
        return view;
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

### fragment_a.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### fragment_b.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fragments in back stack retain their state in a `Bundle`. This includes the view hierarchy state with the current contents of `EditText`s and such.

Comment: I see. I was mistaking the view hierarchy state with the resources associated to it (basically the graphics I think), which are what probably consumes the most memory and is actually destroyed. So when the view is recreated its state is automatically restored and I don't have to worry about doing this explicitly. Okay. Thanks!

Comment: I am calling same fragment  every 3 minutes my view destroyed in fragment after 3 to 5 hours  any solution? please help me

Answer (score -4):

To destroy The Fragment .. Use This `onDestroyView`
 or in `onDetach`

```
     if (fragment != null) {

             fragment =  new YourFragment();
               FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.remove(fragment);
               ft.commit();
        }
```